# ABP vnext: Auto API Controllers: require authentication by default

Tags: abp

How can we require authentication by default for the auto API controllers?

If we add this:

```
        context.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .Build();
        });
```

the auto API controllers require authentication, however the [AllowAnonymous] attribute does not work with specific services.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This fallback policy config should be working. I have tested with both service generated conventional Api and explicit controller Api. The 'AllowAnnoymous' attribute can control if authenticated user is required or not.

You can check if there is corresponding controller defined in your HttpApi project.